# How to save multiple data into local json file with Codable in Swift

Tags: json, swift, apple-watch, codable, healthkit

I am doing iWatch app and I am tracking 4 minutes walk for Heart rate multiple data for each second.

I am getting data and I have to save it to local json file.

I am trying to add data to Codable, but, I am getting only single data.

I am new to Swift.

Following is required format.

```
{   "items" : [
    {
      "endDate" : "2019-12-11",
      "HeartRate" : "82 BPM",
      "startDate" : "2019-12-11"
    },
    {
      "endDate" : "2019-12-11",
      "HeartRate" : "79 BPM",
      "startDate" : "2019-12-11"
    }   ] }
```

Below is my data in main class.

```
    func workoutBuilder(_ workoutBuilder: HKLiveWorkoutBuilder, didCollectDataOf collectedTypes: Set<HKSampleType>) {
              guard let hrType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate),
              let distanceType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning) else {
                  return
          }
          if collectedTypes.contains(hrType) {
              if let hrQuantity = workoutBuilder.statistics(for: hrType)?.mostRecentQuantity() {
                  // We want to have BPM
                  let hrUnit = HKUnit(from: "count/min")
                  let hr = Int(hrQuantity.doubleValue(for: hrUnit))
              //    print("HR: \(hr)")
                self.bpmLabel.setText(String(hr))

                let jsonData = HealthItem.init(endDate: formattedDateFromString()!, HeartRate: String(hr), startDate: formattedDateFromString())
                print("jsonData \(jsonData)")
   }
}
```

struct codable class

```
struct HealThInfo: Codable {
    let items: [HealthItem]?
}

struct HealthItem: Codable {
    let endDate: String?
    let HeartRate: String?
    let startDate: String?
}
```

But, It is saving only single data, Not multiple data.

> jsonData HealthItem(endDate: Optional("2020-02-04"), HeartRate:
>   Optional("87"), startDate: Optional("2020-02-04"))

Comment: Your shown code only prints out a `HealthItem`. Can you show the code that "saves" it?

Comment: I am not yet saving it into local json file, I got stuck over formating itself. Once this gets fixes, Then I can save it into local json file

Comment: You are saving HealthItem data. HealthItem is a single object. You should append HealthItem to 'items' of  'HealThInfo' and save 'HealThInfo'

Answer (score 2):

You can use bellow function

```
func getArrayViaCodable<T : Codable>(arrDict : [[String : Any]]) -> [T]? {
    if let jsonData = try?  JSONSerialization.data(
        withJSONObject: arrDict,
        options: .prettyPrinted
       ){
       do {
           let posts = try JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: jsonData)
            return posts
       } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
       }
   } else {
        return nil
   }
}
```

Now use like

```
if let dictresponse = responsedata as? [String: Any] {
    if let itemArray = data["items"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        let arrHealthInfo : [HealThInfo] = getArrayViaCodable(arrDict: itemArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am taking data in loop from delegate method which will get call 6 minutes continuously. I did not get that from your code

Answer (score 0):

**collectedTypes** is an array of type **HKSampleType**. You should iterate over collectedTypes in order to get all data. Hope it helps you.

Comment: No, I did not get you

Comment: Can you have solution for my issue? my issue with codable class

Answer (score 0):

You never are using the HealThInfo object.

```
let jsonData = HealthItem.init(endDate: formattedDateFromString()!, HeartRate: String(hr), startDate: formattedDateFromString())
let healtInfo = HealThInfo() // maybe load from disk with previous data?
healtInfo.items.append(jsonData)
print("jsonData \(healtInfo)")
```